# How to convert dp value between devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose I have a value say :- 
360dp for a device that is:
Resolution: 1280x800
sw800dp
mdpi

Now I know this dp value works well for the device. How do I calculate the dp value for a device that is:
1024x600
sw600dp

Edit 1:
Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I know what the width must be in dp for a give device typeA with certain resolution R1. How do I calculate the dp value should be for another device typeB with resolution R2?
mdpi

and similarly for a device that is:
2560x1600
sw800dp
xhdpi

I guess what I want to know is how does the math work. What would be the way to calculate the dp value to put in different values files.

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: the dp is the same for all devices. what new value do you want? (what are you trying to acheive?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here we go... We have a online calculator...

https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/

I had a similar problem, so tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

i think below class is complete solution for your present as well as futer problems ,

```
public class DisplayUtil
{
private static int DisplayWidthPixels = 0;

private static int DisplayheightPixels = 0;

private static void getDisplayMetrics(Context context)
{
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    DisplayWidthPixels = dm.widthPixels;
    DisplayheightPixels = dm.heightPixels;
}

public static int getDisplayWidthPixels(Context context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (DisplayWidthPixels == 0)
    {
        getDisplayMetrics(context);
    }
    return DisplayWidthPixels;
}

public static int getDisplayheightPixels(Context context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (DisplayheightPixels == 0)
    {
        getDisplayMetrics(context);
    }
    return DisplayheightPixels;
}

public static int px2dip(Context context, float pxValue)
{
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (pxValue / scale + 0.5f);
}

public static int dip2px(Context context, float dipValue)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dipValue * scale + 0.5f);
}

public static int px2sp(Context context, float pxValue)
{
    final float fontScale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return (int) (pxValue / fontScale + 0.5f);
}

public static int sp2px(Context context, float spValue)
{
    final float fontScale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return (int) (spValue * fontScale + 0.5f);
}
}
```

ex. just you have to call DisplayUtil.Method-Name  !

Answer (score 1):

A set of six generalized densities:
ldpi (low) -120dpi, 
mdpi (medium) -160dpi, 
hdpi (high) -240dpi, 
xhdpi (extra-high) -320dpi, 
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) -480dpi, 
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) -640dpi.

```
If running on mdpi device, 150x150 px image will take up 150*150 dp of screen space.
If running on hdpi device, 150x150 px image will take up 100*100 dp of screen space.
If running on xhdpi device, 150x150 px image will take up 75*75 dp of screen space.
```

Comment: it is usually given reversed, like `150dp is 150px on mdpi, 225px on hdpi, 300px on xhdpi`